# Is it possible to link to an Office Add-in?

Tags: office-addins, excel-addins

Is it possible to create a hyperlink that will open an Office Add-in, if installed on the user's machine?

I am developing an Excel Add-in that presents the user a form that lets them filter and customize what data will be requested from a server and rendered into an Excel sheet.

We would like to be able to send customers a link that would open the Add-in in Excel (if they have it installed), with various query parameters that our Add-in code would use to pre-fill the form for some specific sample request. But I haven't found anything in the docs about whether this is possible.

I am hoping it might work similarly to deep links on iOS/Android apps, which open the app if installed or redirect to the appropriate app store if not. Is this feature available?